# Shortcut for "Jump to" submenu in coderush/refactor pro

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, coderush

Is it possible to set a shortcut for the "Jump to" submenu that shows up when I right click on a method(could be a class, interface etc...) with coderush/refactor pro installed?

I'm using version 3.23 of DXCore, CodeRush and Refactor! Pro, with VS 2008.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create your own shortcut as follows:

1. Open the CodeRush options window (DevExpress > Options...)
2. Select the IDE > Shortcuts item in the treeview
3. Create a new shortcut (the "A*" icon in the toolbar)
4. Specify a new shortcut key (I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>)
5. Make sure the "Enabled" checkbox is checked
6. Change the command to "Navigate"
7. Click OK... job done!

You could probably restrict the scope of the command (with the "Use" treeview), but I haven't really found a need.

Comment: FWIW I use Alt+`=CodeRushTrainingWindowToggle, Alt+1=Refactor and Alt+2=Navigate (listed above). All nice and easy to reach given how close they are to Alt+Tab. :)

Answer (score 6):

I use 9.3.2 and this is now mapped by default to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need to set an extra shortcut, as this option is supported by Visual Studio. 
The standard shortcut is: 
<kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: This is not the same thing (Jump to is much more powerful). But Youre right that CR doesnt impede F12 (unlike R# in some modes!)